# Playwright - closing an angular modal

Tags: typescript, playwright

I am using Playwright to test an angular application.
On the display of a page a modal displays as default.
My test attempts to close the modal by clicking the 'X' element on it.
The element is visible before the click, the click is successful according to debug and trace logs, but the modal does not close.

I have tried:
.. clicking it > once
.. force:true
.. using a dialog handler
.. chaining locators to the modal
.. confirmed it is not an iframe
.. getting the locator from playwright inspector (and various other xpaths that all confirm as correct in dev tools elements and console panel)

Any further suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard to help without the code and the site you're testing as a [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: @antler, hope my below answer would help in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This would help as an alternate way to click:

```
page.$eval(locator, (element ) => element.click())
```